# AppInventor: how to insert DateTime into Google Spreadsheet and show only recent DateTime

Tags: datetime, google-visualization, google-sheets, app-inventor

I am new to this forum so I hope I asking my question in the right place.

I have a problem inserting a datetime into a Google Spreadsheet from a form created in Appinventor2;

In app inventor2 I created a form that fills in a google spreadsheet. Basically I merged the Pizza Party example (http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/pizzaparty.html) with this example http://puravidaapps.com/spreadsheet.php to use google spreadsheet instead of fusion table.

the user selects in how many minutes he wants his order and then sees all the orders in a table sorted by delivery time.

Problem A)
Firstly, i want to save the current datetime + the desired delay into the google spreadsheet and sort the table by this new datetime.

1) when i use the block "call clock format time" + "call clock addminutes" the spreadsheet is populated with a text, but then i can't sort the table by delivery datetime. in fact  i believe the sorting is done on the number regardless of the am/pm or day of the month. so for example instead of having 4am, 6am, 2pm, 3pm i get : 2pm, 3pm, 4am, 6am.

2) I then tried to remove the block "call clock format time" and in the google form i kept the field format = text
but the google spreadsheet is populated with the following:
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1395531335908,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=Europe/Dublin,firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=12,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=22,DAY_OF_YEAR=81,DAY_OF_WEEK=7,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=23,MINUTE=35,SECOND=35,MILLISECOND=908,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]

3) I then tried to remove the block "call clock format time" and in the google form I changed the field format = time
but then the google spreadsheet isn't populated with anything.

4)I tried using the segment block, but after a while I realised the block "format time" actually returns this format: "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
so selecting the 5 characters is not good enough because it does not take into account of the am/pm element as well as the day of the month.

5) I found a temp solution by defining the desired delivery time as a new global variable, and extracting a string in the format hh:mm by joining the blocks ".hour instant" and ".minute instant".
However this is not a final solution because what i extracted is of course a string of text and when sorting, 01:10 will be always considered smaller than 23:50 for example, regardless of the date.

So is there a way of actually saving in the google spreadsheet not a string of text, but actually the date and time?

Problem B)
Secondly, I would like to filter/show only the rows of the google spreadsheet have a delivery time expired by no more than 1 hour (as well as orders with delivery time in the future e.g. in 2 hours from now()).

I tried using some Google Visualization API Query Language commands, altering the url of the google spreadsheet (like WHERE "now() - Delivery Time < 60 mins)" (cannot remember the exact code I wrote) but unsucessfully.

Would anyone know how to filter my results?

thanks in advance

alterettore

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few things to note.

1. If you're using Taifun's example as you mention, you'll notice that when you submit data to Google Spreadsheets using a form, the first column is always a timestamp, even if you're not submitting a date or time.  Trying to send the current date/time is redundant - go ahead and make use of what Google provided.
2. Google Spreadsheets (and Excel) store Date/Time as a number.  If you want to store a date in GS, the best way to do so is not formatted text, but by sending a number.  Use AppInventor to calculate the number you need.  For example, today (April 27) in GS is 41756.  Noon today would be 41756.5
3. To generate this number, start with AI's Millisecond function.  NOTE: Both GS and AI use milliseconds, but they have different 0 points, so you have to manipulate the result a bit.  The formula I've used in AI in the past is this: 
   `GS Date/Time = (Clock1.GetMillis(Clock1.Now) / 86400000) + 25569`

Hope this helps!